# How to show SnackBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to show a SnackBar Widget when the bottom tab is clicked. I am trying to show it as:

```
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
                content: new Text("Live Clicked"),
              ));
```

However the app throws the following exception:

```
I/flutter ( 4965): The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter ( 4965): Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.
I/flutter ( 4965): No Scaffold ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to Scaffold.of(). This
I/flutter ( 4965): usually happens when the context provided is from the same StatefulWidget as that whose build
I/flutter ( 4965): function actually creates the Scaffold widget being sought.
I/flutter ( 4965): There are several ways to avoid this problem. The simplest is to use a Builder to get a context that
I/flutter ( 4965): is "under" the Scaffold. For an example of this, please see the documentation for Scaffold.of():
I/flutter ( 4965):   https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold/of.html
I/flutter ( 4965): A more efficient solution is to split your build function into several widgets. This introduces a
I/flutter ( 4965): new context from which you can obtain the Scaffold. In this solution, you would have an outer widget
I/flutter ( 4965): that creates the Scaffold populated by instances of your new inner widgets, and then in these inner
I/flutter ( 4965): widgets you would use Scaffold.of().
I/flutter ( 4965): A less elegant but more expedient solution is assign a GlobalKey to the Scaffold, then use the
I/flutter ( 4965): key.currentState property to obtain the ScaffoldState rather than using the Scaffold.of() function.
I/flutter ( 4965): The context used was:
I/flutter ( 4965):   MyHomePage(state: _MyHomePageState(603645610))
```

Although the exception is self-explanatory. I don't understand why it is occurring since MyHomePage widget has `Scaffold` in it.

Complete code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'App Name',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'App Name'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var bottomBarLabels = [
    new DestinationLabel(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.live_tv), title: new Text("Live")),
    new DestinationLabel(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.date_range), title: new Text("Matches")),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void _handleBottomNavigationBarTap(int newValue) {
      switch (newValue) {
        case 0:
          print("Live Clicked");
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
                content: new Text("Live Clicked"),
              ));
          break;
        case 1:
          print("Matches Clicked");
          break;
      }
    }

    return new Scaffold(
      key: new Key("homepage"),
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(config.title),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(
          labels: bottomBarLabels, onTap: _handleBottomNavigationBarTap),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You *do* have a scaffold, but not *above* the context of MyHomePage. 
Your Scaffold is a child of MyHomePage, while doing `Scaffold.of(context)` is trying to access the closest *parent* Scaffold. 
And since you have none, it crash.

You should probably wrap your BottomNavigationBar into a new class. And use that widget's context to do `Scaffold.of(context)`.

Answer (score 3):

Change your `_handleBottomNavigationBarTap` method to take a `BuildContext` argument.

```
void _handleBottomNavigationBarTap(int newValue, BuildContext context) {
  ...
}
```

Then change your `bottomNavigationBar` argument as follows:

```
bottomNavigationBar: new Builder(
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return new BottomNavigationBar(
      labels: bottomBarLabels,
      onTap: (index) => _handleBottomNavigationBarTap(index, context),
    );
  }
),
```

This ensures that you call to `Scaffold.of(context)` will be able to find a `ScaffoldState` that is an ancestor of the `context`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I am not able to upgrade my Flutter version at the moment, However, from what I understand, you are trying to show a `SnackBar` only when Live `Icon` is pressed.

So you may want to make the Live `Icon` into an `IconButton` instead and use its `onPressed` property on its own instead of using the `onTap` property of the `BottomNavigationBar`, then wrap the `IconButton` within a `Builder`, something similar to the following:

```
new BottomNavigationBar(
          labels: [
            new DestinationLabel(title: new Text("Live"),
              icon: new Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.live_tv),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          new SnackBar(content: new Text("Live Clicked")));
                    });
              }),
            ),
            new DestinationLabel(icon: new Icon(Icons.date_range),
                title: new Text("Matches"),)


          ],
        )
```

I am not sure if this is the best practice, our Flutter gurus here always suggest to compose the more complex widgets from multiple classes.

Comment: It did not work. I am getting error: `The Argument type 'Builder' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Icon'`

Answer (score 0):

***'showSnackBar**' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use **ScaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar**. This feature was deprecated after v1.23.0-14.0.pre..*

Use Like this:-

```
 ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text('User Successfully Logged In...'),
    ));
```